# How can I set my working folder as a root folder in my project (Windows 10)

Tags: html, windows, frontend

So I'm working in a company where I'm in a UI/UX role, and they have me coding web pages with HTML and CSS. My finished work is then taken by the dev team where they integrate it into the system they are building with Angular. I am planning on learning the basics of Angular next year so I can better help.

Now then, in my HTML or CSS, I'd reference an image with this kind of URL:

```
../assets/img/image-file-name.png
```

The lead developer asked me if I could do them like this:

```
/assets/img/image-file-name.png
```

Obviously with that url, the HTML or CSS would look all the way to the C drive on my laptop for the image, as opposed to relative to the folder. I know I could make this work on a web server with making an .htaccess file with RewriteEngine and RewriteBase, but obviously not on my local machine (unless I'm mistaken).

Granted, I could just make the URLs as I want and then change them before pushing to the repository, but I'd like to work smarter. Any suggestions on how I can fix things up locally so I can basically make my Windows File Folder setup work like it would on the server or some kind of path or trick to have my URLs work correctly in the fashion the lead developer would desire?

Comment: If there is some policy at your work that needs you to show a requirement to install a web server on your work computer, then you have that requirement. Also, you wouldn't need any sort of rewrite rule because the root of the website would be `/` already. It is easy to add the IIS role to Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try windows hard symbolic links or Junction.

Steps :

```
    1. Open cmd as administrator.

    2. mklink /J C:\<project-Root-directory-Name> <Full path to project root directory>
```

Refer:

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/hard-links-and-junctions
2. https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/278262-mklink-create-use-links-windows.html

Hope this helps.