# Problems with favicon, can not make it to show up whenever the path is different than having it saved in the same folder as the html one

Tags: html, href, favicon, ico

`<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/photos/icon.ico" /`> so this does not work

`<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="icon.ico">` but this works having the favicon in the same folder as the html one.
How do I make it so that it will show up having it saved in the photos folder?

Comment: Do you have the favicon file located in `http://www.example.org/photos/icon.ico` (with the replaced host name `example.org` of course)?

Comment: It is located on my drive

Comment: When I have it saved on the same folder as the html one it shows <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="icon.ico"> - this code. but  when saving it on my photos folder and accessing it using this line <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/photos/icon.ico" /> it does not work

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full path where your HTML file is located and the full path where your favicon file is located.

Comment: C:\Users\Johnny\Desktop\root\html and C:\Users\Johnny\Desktop\root\photos

Comment: When you use absolute paths on a local system, you have to place your favicon file at `C:\photos\icon.ico` (when you want to use `/photos/icon.ico` as the absolute path).

Comment: Please check other questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5713295/specify-a-root-path-of-your-html-directory-for-script-links or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59108097/how-can-i-set-my-working-folder-as-a-root-folder-in-my-project-windows-10

Comment: got it to work, just had to use ../ in order to specify the parent folder, thanks for the help kind stranger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its a path problem. you can try one of two things.

1. if on a live server already, you can direct it to where the file is located as this href="https://www.example.com/photos/icon.ico" (remember to path correctly if your photos folder isnt located in public_html)
2. if the resource is located on a local server you can try using "./" (same folder as current page) or "../"(previous folder from current page).

Comment: got it to work, just had to use ../ in order to specify the parent folder

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="photos/icon.ico"/>
```

Removing the first "/" may solve this problem. If it doesn't that is because of the images folder location. The images folder location should be inside the same folder as the html folder. **HTML_folder/photos/icon.ico** is what it technically is saying, but it should look like **photos/icon.ico** .
[image: How files should be organized]

Comment: It works if I am having the image folder in the html one, but I need it to be separated. so it would look something like this root/html/index.html with root/photos/icon.ico and how do I connect the icon to the html w/o having to have to photos folder in the html one

Comment: got it to work, just had to use ../ in order to specify the parent folder